# Всем привет. Требуется помощь в решении задачи

Tags: python, ооп

Создайте класс Person, у которого есть:
конструктор **init**, принимающий 3 аргумента: name, surname, gender. Атрибут gender может принимать только 2 значения: "male" и "female", по умолчанию "male". Если в атрибут gender передается любое другое значение, печатать сообщение: "Не знаю, что вы имели ввиду? Пусть это будет мальчик!" и проставить атрибут gender значением "male"
переопределить метод **str** следующим образом:
если объект - мужчина (атрибут gender = "male"), возвращать строку "Гражданин <Фамилия> <Имя>
если объект - женщина (атрибут gender = "female"), возвращать строку "Гражданка <Фамилия> <Имя>.

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, surname, gender = 'male'):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.__gender = gender
    
    
    @property
    def gender(self):
        return self.__gender
    
            
    @gender.setter
    def gender(self, value):
        if value in ("male", "female"):
            self.__gender = value
        else:
            print("Не знаю, что вы имели ввиду? Пусть это будет мальчик!")
            self.__gender = "male"
    
    def __str__(self):
        if self.gender == 'male':
            return f"Гражданин {self.surname} {self.name}"
        if self.gender == 'female':
            return f"Гражданка {self.surname} {self.name}"
        
p1 = Person('Chuck', 'Norris')
print(p1) # печатает "Гражданин Norris Chuck"
p2 = Person('Mila', 'Kunis', 'female')
print(p2) # печатает "Гражданка Kunis Mila"
p3 = Person('Оби-Ван', 'Кеноби', 'male')# печатает "Не знаю, что вы имели ввиду?  Пусть это будет мальчик!"
print(p3) # печатает "Гражданин Кеноби Оби-Ван"
```

Результат:

```
    Гражданин Norris Chuck
    Гражданка Kunis Mila
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
        print(p3) # печатает "Гражданин Кеноби Оби-Ван"
    TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Вопрос: Что я делаю не так? В ООП новичок как и в питоне.

Comment: если вы правильно поместили текст кода в вопрос, то у вас кавычки съехали в `p3` и пошел коммент посреди текста. Или это и есть причина ошибки, или поместите код правильно для начала:-)

Comment: Добавьте в \_\_str\_\_ вариант возврата строки при else

Comment: Судя по тому, что у Вас в выводе, всетаки съехало форматирование в вопросе. Поэтому привел в тот вид, чтобы при случае указания неверного пола и попытке печати объекта воспроизводилась ошибка которую Вы описываете

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь использовать декораторы `@property` и `@gender.setter`, которые всё-таки являются обычными [геттерами и сеттерами](https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/7.2.php). Они могут использоваться ТОЛЬКО при доступе/занесении данных через уже существующий объект класса и не могут применяться внутри конструктора, если они уже стоят как приватные атрибуты. Если мы будем писать внутри конструктора `self.gender`, то получатся уже неприватные методы, если снаружи писать, то будет не очень красиво.

Если геттер и можно оставить (хотя и его можно убрать, имхо), то сеттер точно убирать надо.

```py
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, surname, gender = 'male'):
    self.name = name
    self.surname = surname
    if gender in ("male", "female"):
      self.__gender = gender
    else:
      print("Не знаю, что вы имели ввиду? Пусть это будет мальчик!")
      self.__gender = "male"


  @property
  def gender(self):
    return self.__gender
    
  def __str__(self):
    if self.gender == 'male':
      return f"Гражданин {self.surname} {self.name}"
    if self.gender == 'female':
      return f"Гражданка {self.surname} {self.name}"

p1 = Person('Chuck', 'Norris')
print(p1) # печатает "Гражданин Norris Chuck"
p2 = Person('Mila', 'Kunis', 'female')
print(p2) # печатает "Гражданка Kunis Mila"
p3 = Person('Оби-Ван', 'Кеноби', 'malf') # печатает "Не знаю, что вы имели 
                                         # ввиду? Пусть это будет мальчик!"
print(p3) # печатает "Гражданин Кеноби Оби-Ван"
```

А вот вариант и без геттера через декораторы:

```py
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, surname, gender = 'male'):
    self.name = name
    self.surname = surname
    if gender in ("male", "female"):
      self.__gender = gender
    else:
      print("Не знаю, что вы имели ввиду? Пусть это будет мальчик!")
      self.__gender = "male"
    
  def __str__(self):
    if self.__gender == 'male':
      return f"Гражданин {self.surname} {self.name}"
    if self.__gender == 'female':
      return f"Гражданка {self.surname} {self.name}"

p1 = Person('Chuck', 'Norris')
print(p1) # печатает "Гражданин Norris Chuck"
p2 = Person('Mila', 'Kunis', 'female')
print(p2) # печатает "Гражданка Kunis Mila"
p3 = Person('Оби-Ван', 'Кеноби', 'malf')# печатает "Не знаю, что вы имели ввиду? Пусть это будет мальчик!"
print(p3) # печатает "Гражданин Кеноби Оби-Ван"
```